# How can I temporarily install tile where radiators were removed in my bathroom?

Tags: bathroom, tile, radiator

I recently bought a very old house and took out the radiators when I installed mini-splits. That means I've got this ugly spot in this small bathroom. I will do a full reno some day, but for now I just want to cover it up with some similar but not perfect tile that I've bought. Since it's temporary and there's no way it ends up looking perfect, I'd rather do a barely adequate job on my own than spend a few hundred on it.

I'm used to minor repairs around the house but have not tiled. I'm moderately confident in how I'll cut and install the actual tile, but want to be sure I properly prepare this spot before doing that. Any advice on how to do that? I think I may have to glue in a board or something on the wall and chisel away at the floor concrete.

Many thanks for any real advice!

[image]

Comment: Have you thought about adding a similar size cabinet there, to cover it until you redo?  Might look better and be useful than a patched tile job.

Comment: Most all of the people answering here have years of experience in home repair and remodeling.  It is difficult for me, ( and I have to believe others.) to formulate a way to do a barely adequate , ( poor) job.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour]. If you just want help fitting backer, revise to show us what's behind the drywall.

Comment: A solid panel painted an appropriately matching color would be much nicer than an obvious kinda/sorta tile approximation.